# Add multiple audio tracks with several languages to video stream

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

we need to mix one video stream with 31 audio tracks, so you can switch in vlc to different languages.

we have video stream in webm and 31 audio streams as vorbis (ogg) and want to bring them all together in one webm-container.

Video file:
video.webm

Audio file:
language_1.ogg;
language_2.ogg;
.....;

should be muxed in:

video.webm (with 31 language Audio-tracks)

What is the ffmpeg-Script?
Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

The template is

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm
       -i language_1.ogg
       -i language_2.ogg
       -i ...
       -i language_30.ogg
       -i language_31.ogg
       -c copy
       -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a ... -map 30:a -map 31:a
       out.webm
```

Comment: @reoctane Additionally, to set the language metadata: `-metadata:s:a:0 language=fre -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng`, etc.